# Woff fonts from Google Fonts load just fine on Chrome and IE, custom Woffs from personal web server only work in Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts, explorer, woff

I load custom fonts from both Google Fonts and my personal website.

The fonts hosted by Google Fonts and by my server are both .woff and are both loaded via   " of the HTML.

I've tested Google's Roboto and Ubuntu CSS and my Roboto and Ubuntu CSS, and they work in Chrome, but only the Google Fonts versions work in Internet Explorer. Is this a security thing on IE's end? Seems like something M$ would do...

To be clear, the test computer is not my server, and does not have any custom fonts, including Ubuntu, installed. I am able to load and view the CSS files from my server, and download the fonts themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your server don't send the correct font mime type.

Google do send the correct mime, your server maybe not.